# refresh view of fragment in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I would like to **refresh** the view of the latest fragment in backstack. (All my fragments are added to `backstack`)

What I tried is:

**Firstly**, find the latest fragment from `backstack`:

```
Fragment currentFragment = null;

try {
    currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_placeholder);
    return currentFragment;
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return currentFragment;
}
```

**Secondly**, pop the latest fragment from `backstack`:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(); //did I do wrong here??
```

**finally**, add the fragment to backstack again:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, currentFragment, fragmentName);

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But,when I run the above procedure, I end up with blank page. It seems the displayed(latest) fragment get removed, but not add back. Why? How to refresh fragment view? (I do this because my locale is changed, and need to refresh the displayed fragment view)

**============2nd way I tried==============**

After I get the latest fragment `currentFragment`, I also tried to call `onCreateView()` directly in order to refresh the view:

```
currentFrag.onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(), null, null);
```

but I got **NullPointerException**.